# Customizing Lists

Tags: lists, enumitem

Using the `enumitem` package, is it possible to customize latex lists as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Only two columns? What is the horizontal positiong of the gap between the entries... is it in the middle of the page, or just as far as `Nonrestrictive:` is wide? What about page-breaking within the right-hand entry?

Comment: Werner: I didn't mention such details because I thought that if, in principal, it is possible, it should be customized in desired ways anyway.

Comment: So do you just want a 'yes/no' answer? In that case, the answer is, I'm pretty sure, 'yes'. You can use the package to customise the `description` environment, and use `\item[Nonrestrictive:]` etc. in the list. Is that what you mean?

Comment: This could be achieved with a table as well

Comment: cfr: Yes, sorry, my question sounds like simple yes/no question; I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most easily:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}[labelwidth = 0.3\linewidth, labelsep =1.5em, leftmargin = \labelwidth]

\item[Nonrestrictive: ] Grey, a popular colour this season, is not becoming me.
\item[Restrictive: ] The colour grey is not becoming me.
\item[Nonrestrictive: ] My archaeology teacher, who has spent years in Greece, claims that Δελφοί is the most interesting site.
\item[Restrictive: ] An archaeologist who has spent years in Greece claims that Δελφοί is the most interesting site.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

(This code to be compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, for trivial reasons).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ebgaramond,paracol,lipsum}
\let\oldparacol\paracol
\renewcommand{\paracol}{%
  \renewcommand{\Nonrestrictive}{%
    \leavevmode\hfill Nonrestrictive:\switchcolumn\noindent% First use
    \renewcommand{\Nonrestrictive}{%
      \par\medskip\switchcolumn*\leavevmode\hfill Nonrestrictive: \switchcolumn\noindent}}% Subsequent use
  \oldparacol}
\newcommand{\Nonrestrictive}{}
\newcommand{\Restrictive}{%
  \par\medskip\switchcolumn*\leavevmode\hfill Restrictive: \switchcolumn\noindent}

\columnratio{0.3}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \Nonrestrictive
  Gray, a popular colour for this season, is not becoming to me.

  \Restrictive
  The gray colour is not becoming to me.

  \Nonrestrictive
  My archaeology teacher, who has spent years in Greece, claims Delphi
  is the most interesting site.

  \Restrictive
  An archaeologist who has spent years in Greece claims that Delphi
  is the most interesting site.
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The location of the column gap can be adjusted by changing the `\columnratio` (currently set to 30%/70%). Switching between columns is done using macros `\Nonrestrictive` and `\Restrictive`. An attempt has been made to have similar usage, but different definition for the first use of `\Nonrestrictive`.